# Fixer.io: is there any way to get the currency description from a symbol?

Tags: currency, fixer.io

I am implementing an app using the **[Fixer.io API](https://github.com/hakanensari/fixer)**.

I wanted to retrieve the following:

- currency description from a symbol (e.g. from EUR get EURO)
- currency icon from a symbol

Is there any way to do so?

**EDIT:**

To obtain the **description** I am thinking of using the native iOS class **nslocale**:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1642814-currencysymbol

Answer (score 0):

There's a display name in the Supported Symbols Endpoint:

`{
  "success": true,
  "symbols": {
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram",
    [...] 
    }
}`

If you want to get the display name in another language, you can also use the java.util.Currency which has a method for names in local languages.

Or you can also give a try to the Java API for Fixer.io:
https://github.com/lico/jFixer

See also Fixer.io documentation:
https://fixer.io/documentation#supportedsymbols